# how to make a mapping between Spring Data JPA Entity and tables related by inheritance

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Postgres 10.8, Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.1.9 with Data JPA to map my Entities with my database table. In my database, I partitioned my tables and use an inheritance strategy.

My structure keeps like this:

[image]

My Entity :

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "my_table", schema = "public")
public  class MyTableEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer 

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
  ...
```

When I try to get or update some rows, I have no problem. But when I save some data in the `my_table`, I get this error:

> ERROR 32759 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   p.c.l.s.web.error.ErrorControllerAdvice  : Unexpected row count: 0;
>   expected: 1; statement executed:
>   HikariProxyPreparedStatement@2106528986 wrapping insert into
>   public.my_table (id, description, created_at) values (10, 'Descripotion ', '2019-12-26
>   11:56:29.091000-03'); nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Unexpected row count:
>   0; expected: 1; statement executed:
>   HikariProxyPreparedStatement@2106528986 wrapping insert into
>   public.my_table (id, description, created_at) values (10, 'Description', '2019-12-26
>   11:56:29.091000-03')
>
> org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException:
>   Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed:
>   HikariProxyPreparedStatement@2106528986 wrapping insert into
>   public.my_table (id, description, created_at) values (10, 'Description', '2019-12-26
>   11:56:29.091000-03'); nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Unexpected row count:
>   0; expected: 1; statement executed:
>   HikariProxyPreparedStatement@2106528986 wrapping insert into
>   insert into
>   public.my_table (id, description, created_at) values (10, 'Description', '2019-12-26
>   11:56:29.091000-03')  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:339)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:254)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
>     at
>   com.mechague.soft.service.impl.MyServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$27b46df5.createItem()

I think that maybe the problem is caused by the trigger that redirects the data to insert in the child table and Spring Data does not recognize it.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a known issue when using partitions with postgresql, it is a part of thier goals to fix this issue [ref](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Table_partitioning#INSERT)

So in simple words hibernate try to ckeck if the insert is realy done by counting the number of impacted lines, but hibernate recognize only the table "my_table" where no insert was performed.

to solve this issue you should tell hibernate to not check rows count by adding the following annotation to your entity

```
@SQLInsert(sql =[YOUR_INSERT_QUERY], ResultCheckstyle = ResultCheckStyle.NONE)
```

Another solution could be the following (but be careful about performance):

- modify your trigger to return NEW , thus a line is inserted to
  "my_table"
- add a second trigger to delete the inserted row

Comment: Thanks a lot @hasnae, I didn't know about SQLInsert, I tried it and founds, but finally I decided to migrate to Postgres 12 and use Real Declarative Partitions, I have to add the create_at like a PK with the id and it founds. I don't know if is the better options but I think that is a good solution